# How to determine which fraction to use in Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I wish to find the Laurent series for the function

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)}$$

on the annulus $2 < |z+2| < 3$.

From the bounds of the domain I deduce that we would like something of the form
$$\frac{|z+2|}{2} > 1, \quad \frac{|z+2|}{3} < 1$$
so that we can use geometric series about the point $z = -2$. Furthermore, using partial fraction decomposition I have that
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z}.$$

My question now is before manipulating the above any further, how do I know which of the above two fractions to expand as a Taylor series and which as a Laurent series? The texts I have referred to all gloss over this heuristically, which makes me believe I am missing obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "about the point $z=2$", but I think you mean about the point $z=-2.$ That is your home base. Let $f_1(z)=1/(z-1)$. This $f_1(z)$ is analytic in a disc (centred) at $-2$, of which your annulus is a subset.

Let $f_2(z)=1/z$. This $f_2(z)$ is NOT analytic in any disc at $-2$, of which your annulus is a subset. So this is the one for which you need to use Laurent's Theorem.

(Of course $f_2$ is analytic in small discs at $-2$, but these don't help you.)

You should, if you haven't yet, sketch the annulus and mark the two isolated singular points of $f(z)$.

Comment: Yes that is a typo sorry. Your tip of graphing really cleared things up, so essentially we use a Laurent series when would like to expand *outside* a circle, and a Taylor series when we are within it?

Comment: Yes, that sums it up well. Note that the (open) outside of a circle is considered an annulus too, although not quite donut-shaped. (some kind of infinite donut). Even the full plane with a single point poked out is an annulus, and Laurent's Theorem is applicable. For example, note that $1/z$ is **the** Laurent series of $f_2(z)$ about the origin, valid in the annulus $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm clear on this, if I'm given say a punctured infinite disk, where the puncture my point is a singularity, then I would use Laurent series to represent my function?

Comment: You can, so long as it is analytic (holomorphic) in that punctured infinite disk. In this case the representation is unique; it is the Laurent series for the function with respect to that domain.

Comment: Got it, thank you for all the help!